# Is it possible to apply multiple filters to a single route in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, filter, routes, controller, codeigniter-4

I have tried several ways to achieve this, but none seems to work,
it seems CodeIgniter 4 does not have the ability to apply multiple filters to a single route, currently here is what I am trying:

ProvideInfoFilter.php:

```php
<?php namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class ProvideinfoFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        echo "pinfo";
        $account_data  = new \App\Libraries\Account_Data; 

        return $account_data->no_info_redirect();
    } 

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {

    }
}
```

AccessFilter.php:

```php
<?php namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class AccessFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $account_data = new \App\Libraries\Account_Data; 

        echo "accessf"; 
        if ($request->uri->getSegment(1) !== 'm' && $request->uri->getSegment(2) !== 'm' && !$request->getGet('token')) 
        {
            return $account_data->is_logged_in();
        }
    } 

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    { 

    }
}
```

Filters.php:

```php
<?php namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{ 
    public $aliases = [ 
        'toolbar'  => \CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar::class, 
        'accesscontrol' => \App\Filters\AccessFilter::class, 
        'provide_info'  => \App\Filters\ProvideinfoFilter::class
    ];
 
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [   
        ],
        'after'  => [
            'toolbar' 
        ],
    ];
 
    public $methods = [];
 
    public $filters = [  
            'provide_info' => ['before' => ['user', 'user/*']],
            'accesscontrol' => ['before' => ['user', 'user/*']] 
    ];
}
```

*I have added echo statements for debugging*

The problem is, Commenting out either `'accesscontrol' => ['before' => ['user', 'user/*']]` or `'provide_info' => ['before' => ['user', 'user/*']]` applies either of the filters the and the echoed string can be seen in the output. But having both of them like demonstrated above does not apply both of them.

It is important for me to have both filters running as I want to apply specific exemptions for each of them using the $globals array.

Comment: You should not return something in your before filters if you want multiple of them running one after the other. What's returned with `$account_data->is_logged_in()` and  `$account_data->no_info_redirect()`?

Comment: @ViLar both returns a CI 4 redirect object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return a Responce instance in a before filter it will be sent back to the client and the script execution will stop. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/filters.html#before-filters

It's normal then that your second filter doesn't run.

In general, avoid to return anything in a before filter if you want it to not stop your script.

Comment: I realized this, and had to make the second filter an after filter.

Answer (score 5):

You are already created 2 filters which are right after that you have to create a `alias` of both `filters` on `Filter.php` file.

After that you have to open `app/config/Feature.php` file and chage this:

```
public $multipleFilters = false;
```

To

```
public $multipleFilters = true;
```

After that you go to `app/config/routes.php` file and then
if you create single route then

```
$routes->get('home', 'Dashboard::index', ['filter' => ['ProvideinfoFilter','AccessFilter']]);
```

In case you want to use `group` then:

```
$routes->group('msp', ['filter' => ['authGuard','AdminAuth']], function($routes){
    $routes->get('/', 'MSPController::msp');
    $routes->get('list_data', 'MSPController::list_data');
});
```

For more information follow this [Codeigniter 4 Doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=routes)

Comment: Codeigniter lacked these features when this question was asked, but future generations would need this.

Comment: Yes true, I have one question is the multi-filter only allow 2 filter max at a time or more? Because as defined way above, when I passed more than 2 filters it does not respond.